Any way to show that second-order logic is incomplete by means other than using Gödel's incompleteness theorem?
I know a way to show second-order logic is incomplete (in the sense of full semantics).
the proof is as follows.
the second-order arithmetic $\mathbf{Z}_2$ or the second-order peano arithmetic $\mathbf{PA}_2$ are consistent r.e. theories and the Robinson arithmetic $\mathbf{Q}$
can be trivially translated into these theories, so there is an arithmetic formula $G$ for these theories that is not provable and not disprovable by Gödel's incompleteness theorem.
But these theories characterize the standard model of natural numbers up to isomorphim by second-order full semantics.
So there is a unprovable tautology therefore second-order logic is incomplete.
Is there any other way to prove that second-order logic is incomplete by means different from this?
I would appreciate any help!

Strictly speaking it isn't meaningful to say that a logic - construed semantically, anyways - is (in)complete. Completeness is a property of a pair [proof system, semantics]; when we say "first-order logic is complete" we mean "there are several 'nice' proof systems which are complete w/r/t the semantics of first-order logic," while "second-order logic is incomplete" means "there is no 'nice' proof system for second-order logic which is complete with respect to its semantics."
However, even this is a bit of an abbreviation. In FOL, due to compactness (and the presence of the Booleans $\wedge$ and $\rightarrow$) we don't have to distinguish between valid entailments and valid formulas: the set $A=\{\langle \Phi,\psi\rangle: \Phi\models_{\mathsf{FOL}}\psi\}$ is determined by the set $B=\{\psi: \emptyset\models_{\mathsf{FOL}}\psi\}$ in the sense that $\langle\Phi,\psi\rangle\in A$ iff there are $\theta_1,...,\theta_n\in\Phi$ such that $(\theta_1\wedge...\wedge\theta_n)\rightarrow\psi$ is in $B$. This of course breaks down in SOL, so in a very coarse sense no proof system can possibly be complete for SOL with respect to entailments, as long as we preserve the rule that proofs must be finite (and so invoke only finitely many hypotheses).
Since this is fairly trivializing, though, we probably really actually want to focus on the analogue $B_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ of $B$. At this point, the incompleteness of any "reasonable" proof system amounts to saying that $B_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ is not computably enumerable. This is immediate as soon as we have a way of implementing computer programs inside arithmetic, since we can in an SOL sentence express (for any program $P$)

If the domain is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{N}$ then $P(n)$ does not halt, where $n$ is the Godel number of this sentence.

(Godel numbering still works for SOL, since that's a purely syntactic, not semantic, process.) The point is that this sentence is in $B_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ iff $P(n)$ fails to halt (where $n$ is its Godel sentence) in reality, and this shows that $B_{\mathsf{SOL}}\not=ran(P)$.
I would argue that this is genuinely different from the incompleteness of PA/Q/etc. The reason is that the above argument generalizes to show that $B_{\mathsf{SOL}}$ (or even its existential-second-order fragment) is not even arithmetically definable, while the set of theorems of PA is very much arithmetically definable. So this is coarser in a genuinely meaningful way. But of course it uses much of the same intuition (including the diagonal lemma), so one's mileage may vary here.
